# Bootstrap 3 dropdown not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I don't really understand, when I launch my html page on local the dropdown menu doesn't work.

I tried to copy/paste my html code on bootply and its work! Incredible ...

http://bootply.com/90610

Any idea ?

I don't want to include all js file, just necessary file for dropdown (dropdown.js)

I didn't really know what I should try ...

If any one can help me It will really appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Firebug console errors :
TypeError: $ is undefined
 

$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()

index.html (ligne 11)
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to include jQuery 1.X or 2.X when you put this in your own HTML page (Bootstrap versions before 3.3.7 [are not compatible with JQuery 3.X](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834)). Make sure to include jquery.js **before** bootstrap.js (or dropdown.js). Usually you do this just before the `</body>` tag.

This is a complete working example, Bootstrap and jQuery are loaded from external CDNs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<!-- Static navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- include javascript, jQuery FIRST -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Put this in a .html file and open it in your browser.

Comment: I don't want to add the complete jquery file, its heavy and not really "safe".
Which function is used in Jquery for dropdown ?

Comment: jQuery is both lightweight and safe. What exactly do you mean by 'not safe'? I have no idea what parts of jQuery are used for a dropdown and I assume it would need quite a lot of digging into bootstrap.js and jquery.js to figure it out ;)

Comment: FYI for readers: Bootstrap 3.X is not compatible with JQuery3.X. You'll need to link to JQuery 2.X or 1.X. [See here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834)

Answer (score 2):

The way i got it working 
First

npm install --save bootstrap@3

this will create all bootsrap dirs for css and js

then i added globally in my project /projectname/angular.json

Added these lines to add css and js

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js"
        ]
```

make sure your index.html file does not directly import any conflicting .js files

Comment: Thank you. This is the only answer that has actually helped me and made it work again - that is importing npm.js after bootstrap.js.

Answer (score 0):

at least for me, all of the above did not fix the problem. 
an upgrade to v3.2.0 of bootstrap did the trick. here is a self-containing sample code. simply copy-paste to a test html file and it should work (all js and css are cdn-loaded):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="btn-group"> 
  <button id="myid" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-    toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```